# What is the Avenging Angel Aura of Menace save DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, saving-throw, paladin, difficulty-class

The party paladin (Oath of Vengeance) is currently 18th level and we are planning on playing to 20th.  Eventually he will get the *Avenging Angel* class feature, which states, in part:

> At 20th level, you can assume the form of an angelic avenger. Using your action, you undergo a transformation...You emanate an aura of menace in a 30-foot radius. The first time any enemy creature enters the aura or starts its turn there during a battle, the creature must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or become frightened of you for 1 minute or until it takes any damage.

There is no DC specified for for the Wisdom save.

As a paladin, the character's *Spell DC* is 8 + Proficiency bonus + Charisma mod.  This seems like the obvious DC to use.  However, in terms of RAW, this ability is *not* a spell.  In fact, I don't think it even meets the [Sage Advice litmus test for a magic ability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical)<sup>1</sup>.

The DMG gives rules for [casting a spell from a magic item when you don't have the Spellcasting ability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106004/23547), but in this case the paladin *is not* casting a spell and *does* have the Spellcasting ability.

The Avenging Angel class feature appears similar to the Draconic Presence class feature, which also does not state a DC.  The sole-and-accepted answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/187986/what-is-the-dc-of-draconic-presence) about Draconic Presence argues for using the Spell Save DC because the Draconic Presence is both fueled by sorcery points and lasts "For 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (as if you were casting a concentration spell)".  The Avenging Angel feature is *not* powered by spell slots (or even a Channel Divinity use) and maintaining it does *not* require concentration.

I think using the paladin's Spell Save DC is a reasonable approach, but I wonder **is there any RAW for setting the DC of a non-spell ability when none is specified?**

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It is not a magic item, not a spell, does not create the effects of a mentioned spell, is not a spell attack, is not fueled by the use of spell slots, and is not explicitly described as magical.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

#### The spell save DC is the only thing it could be.

The description of the Paladin class states:

> Your choice grants you features at 3rd level and again at 7th, 15th, and 20th level. Those features include oath spells and the Channel Divinity feature.
>
> […]
>
> Some Channel Divinity effects require saving throws. When you use such an effect from this class, the DC equals your paladin spell save DC.

The description of Channel Divinity has a line to account for the save DC of Channel Divinity features. This is the closest thing to a rule governing the save DC for the Paladin’s 20th level feature. No other rule even comes close. It should be obvious: use your spell save DC.